# Additive category without finite limits

Tags: category-theory, additive-categories

I was wondering if they are easy examples of additive categories wherein the equalizer or the pullback do not always exist ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a manifold and let $\mathcal{V}$ denote the category of (say) smooth vector bundles. This category is additive but not Abelian. In particular, it does not contain kernels of all of its morphisms, which are equalizers.

A specific example: let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and let $E=\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ denote the trivial bundle, with projection $\pi(x,y)=x$. Define a map of vector bundles $f:E\to E$ by $f(x,y)=(x,xy)$. The kernel of this map does not exist as a vector bundle.